# Java no encuentra archivos en un directorio local

Tags: java, eclipse

Tengo un directorio en local con dos archivos .txt, los cuales estoy intentado listar con java, pero me dice que el directorio está vacío.
He probado a cambiarlos de ruta, puesto que si le especifico en el programa otro directorio diferente me listas los archivos sin problema.

[image: El código es el siguiente:]

Alguna idea de por qué me puede estar pasando esto??
El SO es Windows y mi usuario es administrador

Comment: En que path estan los archivos que no logra encontrar?

Comment: Vale, era exactamente eso... Java no estaba leyendo bien el directorio puesto que existen espacios en el nombre de algunas carpetas. En vez de usar sc.next() de Scanner he usado sc.nextLine() para que  lo leyera de manera correcta y ahora sí me lista todo el contenido. Muchas gracias de todas maneras.

Comment: ¿No era más fácil copiar y pegar el texto que hacer una captura de pantalla y adjuntarla como imagen?

Answer (score 1):

El directorio en el que estaba buscando los ficheros tiene nombres de carpetas que contienen espacios.
Al usar un objeto de la clase Scanner y utilizar la función next() me leía el nombre del directorio hasta que se encontraba con un espacio, es decir, si mi directorio es:
C\kaja_\documentos\Capertas varias\Ficheros
con la opción next(), solo leía hasta:
C\kaja_\documentos\Capertas
de tal manera que buscaba en un directorio que no existe.
Con la opción nextLine() leia la linea entera, independientemente de los espacios y lista correctamente los ficheros.